# Pandas Dataframe adding a dataframe to an existing dataframe and align based on a common column of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to combine two dataframes based on a common column of the two dataframes and searching for a while, but have no luck.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame ([[1,0.3],[2,0.5]],columns = ['Day','Dev'])
df1
   Day  Dev
0    1   0.3
1    2   0.5
df2 = pd.DataFrame ([[1,0.4],[3,0.6]],columns = ['Day','Dev'])
df2
   Day  Dev
0    1   0.4
1    3   0.6
```

Intend to combine like this:

```
   Day  Dev1  Dev2
0    1   0.3   0.4
1    2   0.5   NaN
2    3   NaN   0.6
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: how about : df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.3], [2, 0.5]], columns=['Day', 'Dev'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.4], [3, 0.6]], columns=['Day', 'Dev'])

res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Day', how='outer')

print(res)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first question**

example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame ([[1,0.3],[2,0.5]],columns = ['Day','Dev1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame ([[1,0.4],[3,0.6]],columns = ['Day','Dev2'])
```

ues `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

---

**Update**

when column name is same:

example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame ([[1,0.3],[2,0.5]],columns = ['Day','Dev'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame ([[1,0.4],[3,0.6]],columns = ['Day','Dev'])
```

code

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='Day', suffixes=('1', '2'), how='outer')
```

`out`

```
    Day Dev1    Dev2
0   1   0.3     0.4
1   2   0.5     NaN
2   3   NaN     0.6
```

Comment: Thanks. How about if both df has the same column names: 'Dev', but only align with 'Day'?

Comment: @Brom don't change your question. just update question. i update my answer fo your additional question.

Comment: is there a way to loop, if i have more than 2 df? form df in a list?

Answer (score 0):

pd.merge(df1, df2, on=‘Day’, how=‘outer’)

Have a read about SQL joins to understand the how kwarg.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp